# yaml syntax error for ansible base64 multi line variable

Tags: base64, ansible, yaml

Ansible Version:  2.1.2.0

So I have a yaml file with a multi line variable that's from a binary file converted to base 64.

My variable file: self-cert.yml

```
selfcert: |
MIIKCAIBAzCCCcIGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCCbMEggmvMIIJqzCCBWgGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCBVkEggVV
MIIFUTCCBU0GCyqGSIb3DQEMCgECoIIE+jCCBPYwKAYKKoZIhvcNAQwBAzAaBBQFa98IY7UgblDK
qGwMjTIQCK+3DwICBAAEggTIvA/VFm3j3oSN6cknp5qFyUxXAI5TxURnyx8UVRm8UfMcA0LHlh+z
06ztcwApIrxMSV26ezu0p1FrHInpbABNuO0rlk4XlQwTkLynUyg58iBwK7IyV5SqT2UC8djaOiMN
b9ViC3yn7SrRdS3MmCQznu6dScRIHbhG46yZNJrzrJh038X2KAPpS/LfC9DJBjaEzkZY8BwyARYe
```

When I try to run my playbook that includes this variable, I get:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/projects/install-cert/self-cert.yml': line 3, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

MIIKCAIBAzCCCcIGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCCbMEggmvMIIJqzCCBWgGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCBVkEggVV
MIIFUTCCBU0GCyqGSIb3DQEMCgECoIIE+jCCBPYwKAYKKoZIhvcNAQwBAzAaBBQFa98IY7UgblDK
^ here
```

Any idea whats wrong?  I've tried changing | to > , didn't work, and i've also tried indenting the whole base64 output too.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out you do need to make an indentation to the the multiline variable.  My original indentation was an actual tab instead of spaces (Stupid Sublime) and so  the indentation failed the syntax check, but using actual spaces made everything work.